# usepackage[frenchb]{babel} vs documentclass[francais]{}

Tags: babel-french

Let see the 2 piece of code :

1.using `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{s1}
\section{s1}
\section{s1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2.using `\documentclass[francais]{article}`

```
\documentclass[francais]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{s1}
\section{s1}
\section{s1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why "contents" in the second example is not in french ?

What is the best way to switch in french a latex document ?

Comment: If you look into the log file of your second example, you'll find `Unused global option(s): [francais].` -> if the document class does not know an option, why should it magically change the toc name?

Comment: in the second code you need `
\usepackage{babel}`.

Comment: in  two codes it's better to use `french`.

Comment: @touhami ok, it's working ; By the way, whay is the best solution ?

Comment: @samcarter,  [francais] works fine on my system, but I agree that It would be better to use french

Comment: @flav Concerning why `french` is better: with `frenchb` or `francais` you'll get the warning `Option frenchb for Babel is *deprecated*,(babel-french) it might be removed sooner or later. Please(babel-french) use french instead`

Comment: Moreover, since version 3.9 of babel, language files should be loaded with the `\documentclass`, so that all language-dependent packages be aware of the main language of the document.

Comment: @Bernard is a best practice to place the `usepackage{babel}`?

Comment: Do you mean loading babel without the language option? Yes, the language option should go with the document class, as I said above.

Comment: I misunderstood some thing : I need to \documentclass[french]{article} \usepackage{babel} to have "table des matières" if I omit \usepackage{babel} then it is "contents".